# How to construct an interactive cross table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I wanted to build up a cross table (matrix) in the power BI. I wished to have a way to change the row of the cross table, as I can toggle a button or a property control to change it, as I wish to change the row from the product category to regions so that I can only prepare one table for the end user for them to recieve more information.

It might be clearer if you guys were familiar in spotfire. I could easily edit control to change the expression from property control to enable this primitive interactive feature.

Please also kindly provide some more tutorial for giving interactivity on the table or cross table  for Power BI.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve this issue inside the visual. An option however is to use bookmarks. You make 2 matrix visuals and place them on top of each other. 
Then you can use the bookmark to select which one should be active.

[Bookmarks - Powerbi.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks)

Activate the bookmarks and the selection pane in the view tab.

[image: activate bookmark page]

Use the visibility property to mark it active

[image]

Then you can add a button: matrix 1 and matrix 2.
Clicking the button will change the visibility, and as such the matrix.

[image: button for bookmark]

[Buttons - Powerbi.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-buttons)

Comment: Hi, I don't think bookmark can help me much, since it only showed one status. However, I had the incident of assigning 3 types of column names as well as 3 other types of value shown in the cross table. I think having 9 bookmarks are inconvenient as well.